# Why do I get “estimated error” -1.#IND when doing BICGSTAB linear solver using ILUT perconditioner in eigen

Tags: numerical-methods, eigen, numerical, numerical-analysis, eigen3

I want to ask a question, when I use eigen (C++ library, do numerial linear computing) to solve a linear equations, I use bi-conjugate gradient BICGSTAB with Incomplete LU preconditioner, however, the result bg.error()("estimated error") becomes -1.#IND, after 1 interation, the size of the linear equations is 20000, could anyone help me about this problem? I also tries other small size, e.g, 200, and that is OK.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? As far as I remember `-1.#IND` corresponded to [NaN (not a number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) with that compiler. It means that something went wrong during the computations, for example a division by zero happened.

Comment: @Ali:Yes,I use Visual Studio. But why there is something wrong, and it shouldn't, because the algorithm in eigen should be correct, my matrix is correct.???